# How do I query for content that has not been updated (no revisions)?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I am creating an API endpoint that serves as a content Feed that pulls in content according to some rules.

One group of content that I want to pull is articles that have been updated *and* that have been approved to be included in the feed. My approach for this was to include a boolean field for including it in the feed, and query for the number of revisions.

```
$firstGroup = $query->andConditionGroup()
    ->condition('type', ['article', 'video_game'], 'IN')
    ->condition('status', NodeInterface::PUBLISHED)
    ->condition('field_include_in_feed', 1)
    ->condition('revision_uid', '1', '>=');

$nids = $query->condition($firstGroup)->condition($secondGroup)->execute();
```

Based on [this page from the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21d6%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3Afields/8.2.x), I thought `revision_uid` would be a valid field, but I get an error that it is not. Likewise I get an error, if I use `revision` as well.

The error is a Drupal `QueryException` with the message `'revision_uid' not found`.

What is the best way to query for content (with `entityQuery`) that has been updated if I can't use the `revision` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content that has not been updated would only have one revision, so you could count the number of revisions and use a having condition.

First you'll have to join the `node_revision` table to the `node` table

```
$query->leftJoin('node_revision', 'r', 'n.nid = r.nid');
```

Count the number of revisions

```
$query->addExpression('COUNT(n.nid)', 'revision_count');
```

Filter rows with a revision_count higher than 1

```
$query->havingCondition('revision_count', 1, '<=');
```

Comment: This looks like a great way to do it, but is it possible with `EntityQuery`? The `leftJoin()` function seems to only be available on the `Select` class from `Drupal\Core\Database\Query`.

Answer (score 0):

Every entity stores a timestamp for when the node was created, as well as another for when the node was last updated. So, ideally, you could add a condition to your EntityQuery checking to see if the `created` value matches the `updated` value.

Unfortunately, the standard `condition()` syntax can't handle this. Drupal 7 gave us the `where()` syntax to execute arbitrary SQL that the Entity Query system couldn't handle, but this is not available in Drupal 8. Therefore, you have a couple of options as I see it:

1. Use a subquery to pull the `created` value, then use that returned value as the comparison value against `updated` in the main query.
2. Abandon (unfortunately) EntityQuery and use a dynamic or static query instead.

EntityQuery has some restrictions that are hard to get around, and field-to-field comparison is definitely one of them. Unfortunately, I don't know any other way to know definitively that an entity has been modified without revision info.